# Powershell remoting executing SQL Server installation msi fails

Tags: sql-server, powershell, chef-infra, powershell-remoting

I am trying to use Powershell remoting invoking "chef local mode" on a remote virtual machine.

I am using Powershell code like: `invoke-command -session $session -ScriptBlock{}`

The code invoking chef recipe works fine on the remote VM remote desktop Powershell window.

But it always fails entering "invoking msi" step of that recipe.(I am using official chef SQL Server recipe by the way).

Error log doesn't show anything, but it looks exactly like me manually force closing popup dos windows of SQL Server installation Application while installing locally on the remote VM.

Is there a restriction on Powershell remoting about new window spawn or something?

I had similar problem invoking MSI directly using Powershell scripts, which I had to work around with schedule a Windows task first and kick off it immediately.

Comment: Actually, I think this problem is related to this one [here](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-1172), it seems a bug from Winrm. But unfortunately, after applying the hotfix, I am still having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell remoting is subject to severe constraints, see [Quota Management for Remote Shells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309367(v=vs.85).aspx), most importantly `MaxMemoryPerShellMB` which is 1GB default. Even if the unnattended SQL instalation is correct, the MSI will likely run out of memory due to this constraint. The default values can be modified, see [Learn How to Configure PowerShell Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx).

But is very likely that you're running incorrectly the unattended installation. Remote sessions are not allowed to interact with the Desktop, so no, they cannot spawn windows. Read [Install SQL Server 2014 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) and [Install SQL Server 2014 Using a Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx). Only after you validated locally that the unattended installation is correct, attempt to run it remotely.

I don't know what the 'official SQL Server' recipe does, but I wouldn't trust any such. I would make sure I run a correct unattended installation and build my own recipe from that.

Comment: I have tested both my home-made Powershell script (invoking SQL Server unattended installation with Configuration file) and Chef Recipe (also using similar Configuration file) on the VM locally.

Comment: The installation were successful for home-made Powershell Script & Chef Recipe. And I have tried to increased MaxMemoryPerShellMB  to 2GB. Failed as before. So it may come down to the spawn window restriction. I have checked both ways uses definitely "full quiet" attentions mode. But that dos window still pops out although doesn't require user input.

Comment: Does your configuration specify `/Q` quiet mode, and `/HIDECONSOLE`?

Comment: /Q was used but /HIDECONSOLE was not. I tried to add /HIDECONSOLE. OK from local Powershell. That dos window doesn't pop up anymore.But still same failure from remote. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, I am still hitting same problem after applying Hotfix from Microsoft. And again, I picked up workaround using schedule job to execute installer. This is acceptable approach in Vagrant Core 1.6

> The most difficult part of the plugin was the elevated runner which takes any commands and runs them through a scheduled task instead of directly through the current WinRM shell. This whole rigamarole is needed because of the Windows permission model. You may be running your WinRM shell as Administrator, but its not the same as running Administrator locally on the box. This leads to all kinds of unexpected errors for users trying to install software on a Windows guest.

via [here](http://www.codingonstilts.com/2014/06/vagrant-windows-to-vagrant.html)

and implementation code from Vagrant is [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/efd1d5e11bfc5a72c7a1d1eae294b4751d841544/plugins/communicators/winrm/scripts/elevated_shell.ps1.erb)